# parse_str(): Calling parse_str() without the result argument is deprecated

Tags: php

I have this :
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: parse_str(): Calling parse_str() without the result argument is deprecated

when I update my localhost
how can I fix it ??

```
    if ($result) {
        parse_str(parse_url($result->you_tube_url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
```

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: parse_str(): Calling parse_str() without the result argument is deprecated

Filename: models/System_model.php

Line Number: 62

Comment: [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) returns an array and [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) expects a string. You need to supply the result parm for parse_str.

Comment: if you specify a component, parse_url does return a string,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code relies on very dangerous behavior, since it can overwrite arbitrary variables in the current scope. You could mimic that behavior by changing the code you posted to:

```
if ($result) {
    $tmp = [];
    parse_str(parse_url($result->you_tube_url, PHP_URL_QUERY),$tmp);
    extract($tmp);
```

(provided you don't have a variable called `$tmp`). But you should not fix it that way.

Don't use `extract`. It's much better if you check what variables you want from `$result->you_tube_url`, and define them one by one. For example:

```
  $id = $tmp['id'];
```